# How To - Name a Schema from a Returned Variable in a Stored Procedure?

Tags: mysql

I have an archiving job to do where I need to allow the user to input a customer ID. From this, the stored proc needs to select the customer name, remove all the spaces from the name and create a schema with that name.
So far I have:

```
call ArchiveCustomerRecords_proc(41)
```

This should pull up customer "Fred Schmidt". Then the stored proc should go ahead and create a schema named "FredSchmidt". I have not been able to get the sp to do the REPLACE() and I have not been able to get it to create the schema, other than a string literal for a schema name.

Here's some of the code I've tried, none of it works.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `ArchiveCustomerRecords_proc`(IN CustID Integer)
BEGIN

-- Declare CustName varchar(50);

-- Set @s = 'CREATE SCHEMA ?';

-- PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s; 

SET @CustName = 'Select CustomerName from tblCustomer where CustomerID =' CustID;

SET @CustName = REPLACE(@CustName,' ', '');

-- SET CustName = CONCAT('CREATE SCHEMA ',CustName);

-- EXECUTE stmt1 USING @CustName;

-- DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

    SET @s = CONCAT('CREATE DATABASE ', @CustName);
    PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt1;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
END
```

I finally figured it out.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `ArchiveCustomerRecords_proc`(IN CustID Integer)
BEGIN

DECLARE CustName varchar(50);

Select CustomerName into CustName from tblCustomer where CustomerID = CustID;
Select REPLACE(CustName,' ', '') into CustName;

SET @SQL = CONCAT('CREATE DATABASE ', CustName);
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @SQL;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
END
```

Comment: Creating a database named after a record in another database... There are so many ways this can go bad (like what if you have two Fred Shmidts). Don't do this unless you have some really good reasons.

Comment: I could name it after the customer number, but I wanted something a little more user-friendly. It should be trivial to compare a proposed schema name to the existing schema names and append an integer through a do loop if there is a match. We are only talking about ~300 records.